# Codeigniter Error:Undefined offset: 1 while inserting multiple data into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert multiple data into database but getting an error.

[This is the error i am getting after submitting the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wed31.png)
I am new in CODEIGNITER framework so not understanding why I am getting this error.

```
    function savingdata()  

{       

    $this->load->model('Hello_Model');
    $this->load->view('create');
    $this->load->helper('url');
       if((null!==($this->input->post('save')))&& ($this->input->post('save')==true))
            {
                $lr_no = $this->input->post( 'lr_no' );
                $description = $this->input->post( 'description' );
                $boxes = $this->input->post( 'boxes' );
                $courier_partner = $this->input->post( 'courier_partner' );
                $actual_wt_kg = $this->input->post( 'actual_wt_kg' );
                $basic_charges = $this->input->post( 'basic_charges' );
                $oda = $this->input->post( 'oda' );
                $amount = $this->input->post( 'amount' );
                $invoice_detail = $this->input->post( 'invoice_detail' );
                $customer_name = $this->input->post( 'customer_name' );
                $place_of_supply = $this->input->post( 'place_of_supply' );
                $payment_info = $this->input->post( 'payment_info' );
                $invoice_id = $this->input->post( 'invoice_id' );
                for($e=0;$e<=count($customer_name);$e++)
                {
                    $data[]=
                [
                  'lr_no'=>$lr_no[$e],
                  'description'=>$description[$e],
                  'boxes'=>$boxes[$e],
                  'courier_partner'=>$courier_partner[$e],
                  'actual_wt_kg'=>$actual_wt_kg[$e],
                  'basic_charges'=>$basic_charges[$e],
                  'oda'=>$oda[$e],
                  'amount'=>$amount[$e],
                  'invoice_detail'=>$invoice_detail[$e],
                  'customer_name'=>$customer_name[$e],
                  'place_of_supply'=>$place_of_supply[$e],
                  'payment_info'=>$payment_info[$e],
                  'invoice_id'=>$invoice_id[$e]

                ];
            }   

               
               $this->Hello_Model->saverecords($data);
               
    }
```

```
Also I want that when I enter submit button the whole page won't refresh.
**Please help me regarding this.**
```

Comment: please show us the screenshoot of view.

Comment: Those 'errors' in your screenshot are just notices. They aren't breaking anything. You can make them dissapear by turning off error_reporting. As to your other question, you will want to use AJAX to send the data to PHP without refreshing the page. Try to do that and if you get stuck, post it as a question and include the code that is giving you an error - not a screenshot, actual code

Comment: @JohnTyner thanxx a lot